# FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format. TimerScript.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/TimerScript.cs:19)

Tags: c#

I receive an error:

> FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
>   System.UInt64.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style,
>   IFormatProvider provider) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/UInt64.cs:351)
>   System.UInt64.Parse (System.String s) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/UInt64.cs:99)
>   TimerScript.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/TimerScript.cs:19)

Below is code:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TimerScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float WaitTime = 7200000.0f;
    public Button OpenButton;
    public ulong lastCheastopen;
    public Text FreeCaseText;

    void Awake()
    {
        lastCheastopen = ulong.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastCheast"));
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        OpenButton = GetComponent<Button>();

        if (!IsCheastReddy())
        {
            OpenButton.interactable = false;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
    if (!OpenButton.IsInteractable())
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastCheast", lastCheastopen.ToString());
            if (IsCheastReddy())
            {
                OpenButton.interactable = true;
                return;
            }

            ulong diff = ((ulong)DateTime.Now.Ticks - lastCheastopen);
            ulong m = diff / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
            float secondsLeft = (float)(WaitTime - m) / 1000.0f;
            int seconds = ((int)secondsLeft % 60);
            int minutes = ((int)secondsLeft / 60) % 60;
            int hours = ((int)secondsLeft / 3600) % 24;

            string TimerString = string.Format("{0:0}H {1:00}Mim {2:00}Sec", hours, minutes, seconds);
            FreeCaseText.text = TimerString;
        }
    }


    public void OkCklickButton()
    {
        lastCheastopen = (ulong)DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastCheast", lastCheastopen.ToString());
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        OpenButton.interactable = false;
       // lastCheastopen = ulong.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastCheast"));
    }

    private bool IsCheastReddy()
    {
        ulong diff = ((ulong)DateTime.Now.Ticks - lastCheastopen);
        ulong m = diff / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        float secondsLeft = (float)(WaitTime - m) / 1000.0f;

        if (secondsLeft < 0)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your awake method. What is the output of the PlayerPrefs.GetSTring("LastCheast"); call? could you save that into a string variable and give us the output pls?

Comment: public ulong lastCheastopen = 636400511496774752; I can not get the value after running the script. and get an error

Comment: If you cannot get the value after running the script, then that is the reason for the error: Probably it is empty string or null, therefore it cannot be parsed as a uint.

Comment: Just a nit pick here, but shouldn't it be lastCheastOpen for proper camel casing?

Answer (score 1):

try:

lastCheastopen = ulong.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastCheast", "0"));